# Primitive roots for composite modulus

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $a$ is a primitive root modulo $m_1m_2$, prove that $a$ is a primitive root modulo $m_1$ and modulo $m_2$.

This is what I have so far:

$$\text{$a$ is a primitive root mod $m_1m_2$}$$
$$order_{m_1m_2}(a) = \varphi (m_1m_2)$$
$$a^{\varphi(m_1m_2)} \equiv 1 \pmod{m_1m_2}$$
$$\Rightarrow a^{\varphi(m_1m_2)} \equiv 1 \pmod{m_1} \text{ , } a^{\varphi(m_1m_2)} \equiv 1 \pmod{m_2}$$
$$\varphi(m_1) \lt \varphi(m_1m_2)$$
$$\varphi(m_2) \lt \varphi(m_1m_2)$$
$$\text{so we can say}$$
$$a^{\varphi(m_1)} \equiv 1 \pmod{m_1}$$
$$a^{\varphi(m_2)} \equiv 1 \pmod{m_2}$$

I'm just not quite sure of how to go the next step to show $order_{m_1}(a) = \varphi(m_1)$ and $order_{m_2}(a) = \varphi(m_2)$.

Comment: In a sense, this is a peculiarly weak result. For the only numbers that are not prime powers and have a primitive root are numbers of the form $2p^k$, where $p$ is an odd prime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $m_1$ and $m_2$ are coprime, and fix $a$ coprime to $m_1m_2$. Suppose that $a$ is *not* primitive mod $m_1$.  Then
$a^d=1 \mod m_1$, for some $d < \varphi(m_1)$ dividing $\varphi(m_1)$.

We have $a^{\varphi(m_2)}=1 \mod m_2$ in general, hence
$$a^{d \varphi(m_2)} \equiv 1 \mod m_1m_2,$$
by the Chinese Remainder theorem.  But this says that $a$ has order dividing $d\varphi(m_2) <\varphi(m_1m_2)$, so $a$ cannot possibly be primitive mod $m_1m_2$.

Switching to the contrapositive, suppose that $a$ is primitive mod $m_1m_2$.  Then $a$ is primitive mod $m_1$ from above, and $a$ is primitive mod $m_2$ as well (by symmetry).

Comment: Ah, I see now. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Like Andre stated in his earlier post you must have m1=2 and m2=p^k where p is an odd prime.